# How Do I Add A Button To A Already Existing Object?

Tags: html

I'm Currently Using A Website Base And Would Like To Make The Buttons On The Website Go-To Real Links. Currently, If You Hover Over Them And Click They Do Nothing Since They Are Not Buttons. Just Wondering How To Make It A Real Working Button That Will Redirect Someone To A URL. If You Would Like To Download It, You Can Download It Here : [Mega.nz](https://mega.nz/#!p0xURQZC!t52FSMceX4eLFS8D-w4-HLthwHGAuHMUqEsbLaJ6914)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Answer (score 1):

Your link and your post seems suspicious. I wouldn't click on it.

Here it's how you can create a button with a link in it:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href = 'https://w3docs.com';">Click Here</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i already know how to make a simple button im just trying to make it were and already existing object can be made into a button but keep its properties